# How to select a Modal form and enter data to the input fields using Java

Tags: java, selenium, modal-dialog

I am trying to test login functionality for https://www.expedia.com/  site using Selenium WebDriver with Java. I am also using Page Object Factory design pattern.

Procedure to login is: Go to above site --> Click Account menu --> select 'Sign In' option. 
A new popup Login window appears where I am trying to enter email address and password using my automation script.

Here is my code which handles the Expedia's login form:

LoginPage.java contains:

```
{

    @FindBy(id = "gss-signin-email")
    public WebElement txtUserName;

    @FindBy(id = "gss-signin-password")
    public WebElement txtPassword;

    @FindBy(id = "gss-keep-signin-check-label")
    public WebElement chkBoxKeepMeSignIn;

    @FindBy(id = "gss-signin-submit")
    public WebElement btnSignIn;

    public void setUserName(String uname) {

        txtUserName.click();
        txtUserName.sendKeys(uname);
    }

public void setPassword(String pwd) {

    txtPassword.click();
    txtPassword.sendKeys(pwd);
}

public void setKeepMeSignIn() {

    chkBoxKeepMeSignIn.click();
}

public void clickSignIn() {

    btnSignIn.click();
}
```

}

TC_LoginTest_001.java contains:

{

```
    Page.menu.gotoAccounts();

    Page.menu.gotoSignIn();

    LoginPage lp = new LoginPage();

    driver.switchTo().activeElement();

    lp.setUserName(config.getProperty("username"));

    lp.setPassword(config.getProperty("password"));

    lp.setKeepMeSignIn();

    lp.clickSignIn();
```

}

When I run my script using Run As --> TestNg Suite, I am getting following error message:

```
**LoginTest
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.expedia.pages.LoginPage.setUserName(LoginPage.java:42)
at com.expedia.testcases.TC_LoginTest_001.LoginTest(TC_LoginTest_001.java:38)**
```

Test data are Not being enter in the input fields (i.e. Email address and Password). It looks like my script is not recognizing a Modal form. Kindly suggest how should I resolve this issue.

Comment: Are you able to access txtUserName in the 'setUserName' in debug mode? I did not faced any issue with modal form, when tried with the pyton code added below.

Comment: @supputuri - My script is able to navigate to the Login window, but it cannot access txtUserName or any fields on it.

Comment: are you passing the driver to the class? `LoginPage lp = new LoginPage();` should this be `LoginPage lp = new LoginPage(driver);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have switch to new window to access the element.Here is the complete java code.Hope this helps.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "\\Executables\\Chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.expedia.com/");     
        String parentHandle = driver.getWindowHandle(); 
        WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.id("header-account-menu"));
        Actions action=new Actions(driver);
        action.moveToElement(element).click().build().perform();
        driver.findElement(By.id("account-signin")).click();
        for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
            driver.switchTo().window(winHandle); 
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
            WebElement elementemail = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("gss-signin-email")));
            elementemail.sendKeys("xyz@gmail.com");
            WebElement elementpass = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("gss-signin-password")));
            elementpass.sendKeys("xxxxxxx");

        }
        driver.switchTo().window(parentHandle); 

        }
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: when I try to run your code, I am getting following error msg:

Starting ChromeDriver 74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}) on port 1225
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 74
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
 at com.expedia.rough.LoginTest.main(LoginTest.java:18)

Comment: `This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 74 ` this statement is saying you have lower version of chrome browser installed in your machine.Update your chrome browser version.Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. After updating ChromeDriver version from 73 to 74, I was able to run your script. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Hemansu : glad to help you. Can you accept my answer if it helps.

Comment: Sure i can. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the python code which I ran without any issue. `wait_for_element_present` is a method which will wait until element preset and return the webelement.

```
url = "https://www.expedia.com/ "
driver.get(url)

driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#header-account-menu").click()
accountSignIn = wait_for_element_present('css',"#account-signin")
accountSignIn.click()
email = wait_for_element_present('css',"#gss-signin-email")
email.send_keys("hello")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#gss-signin-password").send_keys("hello")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#gss-signin-submit").click()
```

**Java code** equivalent to `wait_for_element_present` in my above code. sample code source form https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp]

```
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("myDynamicElement")));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Since I am using Java language I am not sure whether I can still use a "wait_for_element_present" method in it.

Comment: You should be able to implement the wait_for_element using the code I posted in updated answer. Refer to the link that I added for more information.

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Cool, please select checkbox below the down vote button on the left hand side in my answer to accept my answer.